# "One cluster is not yet connected to the region" after install ubuntu server?

Tags: server, maas

Today was my first install of an MAAS server. So as you can guess I am new to whole concept ;)

After using the MAAS option during install of ubuntu server install it worked really well. I installed the system and the web UI could be opened. After logging in I got two warnings. The first one was easy to solve and was about not having any images for the MAAS. That was a simple google search and was resolved. The other one is not solved yet I do not understand exactly what it means. It is telling "One cluster is not yet connected to the region". So I went to the cluster tab and tried some things, but could not resolve the problem. Some searching on the internet was not the answer either (either not exactly the problem or with an solution that was not working ).

Question: what does "One cluster is not yet connected to the region" mean, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you installed maas with the following.

```
sudo apt-get install maas
```

You can set the region and cluster locations with the following commands.  You'll want to make sure the URLs are correct.  If you have created two interfaces, the cluster controller most likely would be your external network.  (http://192.168.1.1/MAAS/)  Where the region controller would be located on your local network (10.0.0.1).

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple but so effective.

Comment: "maas-cluster-controller is not installed". I initially did `apt install maas`, and that didn't include `maas-cluster-controller`. So should I install `maas-cluster-controller`, or will that break something? I see no "cluster" tab in MAAS, so does this not apply to the latest version (2.4)?

Comment: Ah, the solution was `sudo apt install maas --reinstall`. That installed something. Then I could run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller`.

Comment: There's a good chance that the old information has been outdated over the past 3 years.  Glad you got it sorted! @falsePockets